# What is "zenity" and did it crash?

Tags: 12.04, zenity

I am on Ubuntu 12.04.

I was running the Ubuntu customization kit but it disappeared with the following message: "The application zenity closed unexpectedly". When I further ran it, it just closed after selecting the language option. It was running well on previous Ubuntu versions and I made many remix of Ubuntu with the application.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Zenity is lean tool for creating very simple GUI-Applications from the commandline.

Use zenity --help to see the options:

```
zenity --help
Usage:
  zenity [OPTION...]

Help Options:
  -h, --help                                     Show help options
  --help-all                                     Show all help options
  --help-general                                 Show general options
  --help-calendar                                Show calendar options
  --help-entry                                   Show text entry options
  --help-error                                   Show error options
```

... and so on.

For example, if you issue the command:

```
zenity --info  --text "Just a Demo"
```

displays a small dialog with a light bulb, an OK-Button, and the text "Just a Demo", try it yourself.

The usual way to do more useful things is, to capture the message, produced by zenity:

```
msg=$(zenity ...)
```

To your second question, why it failed: From the short message you reported, it can't be answered.

Comment: Thank you for the info.The failure message showed when I was running Ubuntu customization kit.After I closed the dialogue box,I couldn't run the application any more but it starts with a terminal,and a window to select the language but disappear after i clicked "ok".